# Regex "NOT" exists Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression which matches words which do NOT start with "DEF".

Now I would like to modify it to following three cases:

1. Does NOT END with "DEF"
2. Does NOT Contains "DEF"
3. Does NOT Equal TO "DEF"

what should I modify the string patterns ?

```
Regex pattern Match word which does NOT start with word "DEF":  ^(?!DEF).*$
match word :  ADEFCCC
Does Not Match :   DEFXXX
```

Comment: Are you sure you need regex? Why not `String.Contains(), .StartsWith(), .EndsWith()`?

Comment: yes... i need the regex pattern and send it to Middle tier services..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Does not end with DEF:   ^.*(?<!DEF)$
Does not contain DEF:    ^((?!DEF).)*$
Does not equal DEF:      ^(?!DEF$).*$
```